# Google API to retrieve their Cache of any website

Tags: url, caching, google-api, html

Is there any API from Google that allows me to retrieve their cache for the given URL.

I found this Cache Requests (http://code.google.com/apis/soapsearch/reference.html) but no longer available.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

this is what the cache url looks like for google.com

```
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?sclient=psy&hl=en&biw=1440&bih=728&source=hp&q=cache%3A**www.google**.com&pbx=1&oq=cache%3Awww.**google.com**&aq=f&aqi=g5&aql=1&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=3639l7768l0l8083l20l4l0l0l0l0l194l603l0.4l4l0
```

try using curl or another method to retrive data from an url and replace the domain by ur domain and see if it works.

I tried to replace google by another domain and it worked.

Comment: Works, but not for many requests. You'll get hit by a captcha.